# FadeOut, Replace HTML & FadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a few issues getting a simple JQuery function to work that fades an element out, replaces the image within and fades back in again.

My function looks like this:

```
function nextPage() {
        $("#leftPage").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#leftPage").html="<img src='page4.jpg'>";
            $("#leftPage").fadeIn("slow");
        });

        $("#rightPage").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#rightPage").html="<img src='page5.jpg'>";
            $("#rightPage").fadeIn("slow");
        });
}
```

The fade in/out section works fine but the HTML is not being replaced with the new images. Can you see a problem with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function nextPage() {
    $("#leftPage").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $("#leftPage").html("<img src='page4.jpg'>");
        $("#leftPage").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("#rightPage").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $("#rightPage").html("<img src='page5.jpg'>");
        $("#rightPage").fadeIn("slow");
    });
}
```

You're assigning a string to `.html` which is actually a function that *takes a string as an argument*, instead of being a property you can assign things to.

Notice I've changed `.html = ""` to `.html("")` in the above snippet. This now passes a string to `.html()`, which updates the element accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The [correct syntax for `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is:

```
$("#leftPage").html("<img src='page4.jpg'>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function nextPage() {
        $("#leftPage").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#leftPage").html("<img src='page4.jpg'>");
            $("#leftPage").fadeIn("slow");
        });

        $("#rightPage").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#rightPage").html("<img src='page5.jpg'>");
            $("#rightPage").fadeIn("slow");
        });
}
```

jquery's html is a function, not a property. You pass in the html you want to replace the elements contents with as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#leftPage").html("<img src='page4.jpg'>");
```

and:

```
$("#rightPage").html("<img src='page5.jpg'>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery's `.html()` wrong

```
function nextPage() {
    $("#leftPage").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#leftPage").html("<img src='page4.jpg'>");
        $("#leftPage").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $("#rightPage").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#rightPage").html("<img src='page5.jpg'>");
        $("#rightPage").fadeIn("slow");
    });
}
```